# image are showing in too small in android nexus phone

Tags: android, performance

I created a project to show images as carousel view.When I run this project in so many devices. when it is tested in nexus phone the images sizes show in too small. This is big problem in my project. pls tell me way to over come this problem...

Thanks

Comment: Try using a high resolution image and put it in hdpi folder in res

Comment: provide some more info plz. what have you tried? where do you think is the issue coming from?

Comment: here I can't change the dimension. because the showing images are downloaded from web and show them i carousel view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not put copies of my images in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc because I have far too many images for this approach and the apk size would be too large. (Incidentally, only very old phones use ldpi).

Instead I place all my images in mdpi and enlarge them for tablets (e.g. something like this):

```
        if (isTablet(getActivity())){  // tablets only
           debugLog( "display tablet image="+imagename);
           int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename,"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());                       // the corresponding resource id
           if (resID != 0) {
              Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
              int width=480;
              int height=300;
              Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
              ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tablet_image);  // the imageview to change
              //imageView.setImageResource(resID);
              imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different dimens pls.

Defined different dimens in different devices.

values
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
values-xhdpi
values-nodpi
values-nodpi-1024×600
values-nodpi-1280×800
values-nodpi-800×480

and so on..